# Why nodeValue is not getting me the text between the <span>

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div> 
      <span> $12.95 </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
  console.log(all[i].nodeValue);
}
```

I see null in the console when it gets to the  element. I am wondering how may I be able to get just the text of all the elements in a page? I know that if I use innerHTML I would get the text, but then I would get the text repeated somehow. So, for the `<div>` I would get `<span> $12.95 </span>` and then for the `<span>` I would get `$12.95`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use nodeValue to get the contents then you have to traverse down to the text node that is contained within the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/xLJMb/

```
var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
  console.log(all[i].nodeValue);
  for(var j = 0, max2 = all[i].childNodes.length; j < max2; j++) {
    console.log(all[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue);
  }
}
```

Text Nodes are not elements, so they are not returned directly by getElementsByTagName().

Comment: Mike Edwards. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I have a question though. Why would childeNodes.length of a <div></div> return 1?

Comment: The span is a child of the div, the text node is a child of the span.  The text node is a grand-child, not a child of the div.

Comment: I guess my question was that if a <div> has some spaces between them, like <div>     </div> it would count as it has a childNode.

Comment: Ah.  Well, I believe that behavior will be browser dependent.  Some browsers will scrub the white-space and some will create textNodes with just white-space.  I am using chrome and div.childNodes.length === 3

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use from this html:

```
<div>
    <span id="span">$12.95 </span>
</div>
```

and this Script:

```
console.log($('#span').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

As addendum to the answer above, in modern browser, if you want to iterate only text node, you could use the [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) API:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
  // Using ES6 arrow function, this is removing all "empty" text nodes
  // equivalent to:
  // function (node) { return !!node.nodeValue.trim() }
  node => !!node.nodeValue.trim()
);

while(treeWalker.nextNode())
  console.log(treeWalker.currentNode.nodeValue);
```

Comment: This is interesting. I have found myself with problems because the text node that I get, is used against a REGEX. Then for this kind of stuff <script type="text/javascript"> cmSetupOther({ "cm_TrackImpressions": "SCM" }); </script> -- I am basically screwed. Would treeWalker help?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question here. However, I don't think it would be much different, at the end you obtain always the string of `nodeValue` to use against a regex. I think in your case it depends which text and which regex.

Comment: ZER0 I am trying to get all the prices parsing a site. I want to avoid getting the text that are between <script> tags. As that text is Javascript. I am concerned on what I get, because I will use it against a .match function for regex.

Comment: You could just update the filter function as follow: `node => node.nodeValue.trim() && node.parentNode.tagName !== "SCRIPT"`. Notice that you can do the same check in the answer you accepted, just checking the `tagName`, or, in modern browsers, excluding `script` tag upfront: `var all = document.body.querySelectorAll(":not(script)");`

Comment: Thanks ZER0. I will go ahead and see what is going on. Because it seems sometimes I am getting some values which .match does not know how to deal with.